# Convert array to utf8 encode doesn't work PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, utf-8

I have a splitted string by `str_split` into the array and encode it to UTF-8 using `utf8_encode` and then when i print the array it doesnt print the special characters like `Ł`, below is example of my code. *.php file using UTF-8.

```
$str = "Łukasz";
$aStr = str_split($str);
$aStr = array_map("utf8_encode",$aStr);
print_r($aStr);
```

And here is the result: `Array ( [0] => Ă [1] => Â [2] => u [3] => k [4] => a [5] => s [6] => z )`, So where i made a mistake?

Regards,
Patrick

Comment: _“So where i made a mistake?”_ – in thinking `str_split` would work on a character basis; it doesn’t, it works on bytes.

Comment: So how i should split this string? Is it would work when i split it by `substr`?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the function str_split is not unicode compatible. ASCII characters are using only 1 byte while unicode characters use 2-4.

In the comments of the str_split function in the documentation the user "qeremy" has provided this unicode version of str_split:

```
function str_split_unicode($str, $l = 0) {
    if ($l > 0) {
        $ret = array();
        $len = mb_strlen($str, "UTF-8");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += $l) {
            $ret[] = mb_substr($str, $i, $l, "UTF-8");
        }
        return $ret;
    }
    return preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

Comment: I made a lighter version `for($i=0;$i<mb_strlen($str,'UTF-8');$i++) {
    $aStr[]=mb_substr($str,$i,1,"UTF-8");
}` but it still prints wrong characters instead of `Ł` it prints `Ĺ`